# Displaying records with a column value 0 when there is no record or Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have table like these
`select id,category from table1` and
`select date,id,hrs from table2`

by join I get table like this lets call this **mixTable**

```
   Date     Category     Hrs
 01/23/2017  One         3.5
 01/30/2017  Two         2.3
 01/20/2017  Three       0.6
 01/18/2017  Four        4.3
 02/13/2017  One         6.2
 02/15/2017  Two          4
 02/20/2017  Four        2.2
 03/16/2017  One          1
 03/25/2017  Two         4.3
 03/20/2017  Three       3.6
 03/18/2017  Four        2.5
 04/26/2017  One         2.5
 04/30/2017  Two         3.3
 04/22/2017  Three       2.1
```

I am looking for Output like this **mixTable2**

```
Date    Category    Hrs
Jan-17  One         3.5
Jan-17  Two         2.3
Jan-17  Three       0.6
Jan-17  Four        4.3
Feb-17  One         6.2
Feb-17  Two           4
Feb-17  Three         0
Feb-17  Four        2.2
Mar-17  One           1
Mar-17  Two         4.3
Mar-17  Three       3.6
Mar-17  Four        2.5
Apr-17  One         2.5
Apr-17  Two         3.3
Apr-17  Three       2.1
Apr-17  Four          0
```

As You can see both Tables have **Date, Category** and **Hrs**. In Output table I want to show missing month value as 0 even it is not recorded in the table for ex. **Feb-17** and **Apr-17** are not recorded in the main table. Also the **Category Three** and **Four** are not recorded.

`I'm trying to figure out how to show rows in a table that do not have corresponding values in another table.`

Comment: Can you share your current query?

Comment: Its too big too share here. I will try to give a simpler example.

Comment: isnull(your_value, 0) would handle the 0. Then use a case statement for the other column to show 'Not Recorded'

Comment: @Mureinik `select w.category,w.wonum,w.completed_date,h.hrs from workorder w join workhrs h on w.wonum=h.wonum` this is a simpler form of my query the wonum in Workorder table is primary key whereas the wonum in Workhrs its not.

Comment: This is tagged with DAX. Are you looking for a DAX solution or a SQL solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in TSQL.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ISNULL(h.hrs, 0) = 0 THEN 'NOT RECORDED'
ELSE w.category END AS [Category]
w.wonum,w.completed_date,ISNULL(h.hrs, 0) AS [hrs]
FROM workorder w 
LEFT JOIN workhrs h (NOLOCK) ON w.wonum=h.wonum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in Power BI, I would do the following:

1. Create a calculated column on mixTable for the month:

---

```
Month = EOMONTH(mixTable[Date],0)
```

---

2. Cross join the `Month` and `Category` columns into a new table.

---

```
mixTable2 = CROSSJOIN(VALUES(mixTable[Month]),VALUES(mixTable[Category]))
```

---

3. Created a calculated column on this new table to the sum of the hours.

---

```
Hours = SUMX(
            FILTER(MixTable,
                MixTable[Category] = MixTable2[Category] &&
                MixTable[Month] = MixTable2[Month]),
            MixTable[Hrs])
```

---

4. If you want zeros instead of blanks, wrap the above in `IF(ISBLANK(...),0,...)`.